# How to use selectSnapshot?

Tags: angular, store, ngxs

I have a guard that checks if there is a token on state.

```
canActivate(): boolean {
const token = this.store.selectSnapshot((state: AuthenticationState) => state.token);
  if (!token) {
    return true;
  }

  this.router.navigate(['home']);
  return false;
}
```

Then I have something like this:

```
export class AuthenticationState {
  @Selector()
  static token(state: AuthenticationStateModel) {
    return state.token;
  }
}
```

I get an error.
Property 'token' does not exist on type 'AuthenticationState'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The mistake you are making here is that you are assuming that the state parameter of the lambda would be your `AuthenticationState` it would in fact be the entire application state, which is a parent of the `AuthenticationState`. You should rather pass your selector like this:

```
canActivate(): boolean {
const token = this.store.selectSnapshot(AuthenticationState.token);
  if (!token) {
    return true;
  }

  this.router.navigate(['home']);
  return false;
}
```

There was actually a post by the author of NGXS a few days ago on this exact topic:
https://medium.com/@amcdnl/authentication-in-ngxs-6f25c52fd385

Comment: Is it possible that the `AuthenticationState.token` selector could get state which is undefined. Should you account for undefined state in the selector function?